# How to authenticate with spring security and JWT with user of own database

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

Followed a tutorial and set up `Spring Security` with JWT as following:

WebSecurityConfig.java:

```
package ch.echoport.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests();
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/nextevent").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/api/authentication", authenticationManager()),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // Create a default account
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("admin")
        .password("password")
        .roles("ADMIN");
  }
}
```

JWTLoginFilter.java:

```
package ch.echoport.security;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;

public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  public JWTLoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
    setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    AccountCredentials creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class);
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getUsername(), creds.getPassword(), Collections.emptyList()));
  }

  @Override
  protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain, Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
    TokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(res, auth.getName());
  }
}
```

JWTAuthenticationFilter.java:

```
package ch.echoport.security;

import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

  public JWTAuthenticationFilter() {
    System.out.println("JWTAuthenticationFilter called");
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                       ServletResponse response,
                       FilterChain filterChain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    Authentication authentication = TokenAuthenticationService
        .getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) request);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
        .setAuthentication(authentication);
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

TokenAuthenticationService.java:

```
package ch.echoport.security;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import org.springframework.security
    .authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.Date;

import static java.util.Collections.emptyList;

@Service
public class TokenAuthenticationService {
  static final long EXPIRATIONTIME = 14_400_000; // 4 hours (in milliseconds)
  static final String SECRET = "ThisIsASecret";
  static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer";
  static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";

  public static void addAuthentication(HttpServletResponse res, String username) {
    String JWT = Jwts.builder()
        .setSubject(username)
        .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATIONTIME))
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
        .compact();
    res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + " " + JWT);
  }

  static Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println(request.toString());
    String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
    if (token != null) {
      // parse the token.
      String user = Jwts.parser()
          .setSigningKey(SECRET)
          .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
          .getBody()
          .getSubject();

      return user != null ?
          new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, emptyList()) :
          null;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

AccountCredentials.java:

```
package ch.echoport.security;

public class AccountCredentials {

  private String username;
  private String password;

  public AccountCredentials() {}

  public AccountCredentials(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }
}
```

This all works fine when working with the set up in-memory user in the`WebSecurityConfig`-Class.

Now I want to check if user and password matches with my own database if a user tries to log in, for example with the `BCryptPasswordEncoder`. How do I have to proceed if it matches? Do I have to call the `addAuthentication()`-method in the `TokenAuthenticationService`? If so, what do I have to pass as the first argument (`HttpServletResponse`)? If not, what steps do I have to take?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use User Detail Service for authentication. Create your own service implements UserDetailsService and call load user by user name method from web security config class. Ignore auth in memory propery use auth.userDetailsService() method give your service as parametre this method.

You can look up https://github.com/farukkkaradeniz/JwtAuthentication for authentication from database

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    Users user = userRepository.findOneByUserName(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User '" + username + "' not found");
    }

    return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
            .withUsername(username)
            .password(user.getPassword())
            .authorities(Collections.emptyList())
            .accountExpired(false)
            .accountLocked(false)
            .credentialsExpired(false)
            .disabled(false)
            .build();

}
```

Comment: thank you so far. I should get a JWT from this which I can send to the Client, or am I wrong?

Comment: You can check repository from github. First you make post request for login url and this returns you token in header. After this you can make all request with this request.

Comment: Hi Faruk, I made post request for login url but it didn't return token in header as I checked the response body and header. I'm testing it with postman. Plz suggest how to get that one. Bcz login is successful but without passing that generated JWT toke, I am unable to hit another service url. Thanks.!